# Delete multiple branches at one go - PhpStorm

Tags: git, intellij-idea, phpstorm

Is there a way to delete multiple branches at one go in PhpStorm?

When I am searching I am having the option of deleting it one by one.

Comment: I assume you know this, but if this is just a one time thing, it's simple to do it from a command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to Git toolwindow, in Branches pane, while holding `Shift` choose branches with `left click` and then -> `Right click` -> `Delete branches`